# Passing an NSArray to a screen and displaying its contents in a table

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am working on a navigation based application for the iPhone.  At present, I have an NSArray in the RootViewController.m class, which I want to pass to the SecondViewController.m (the second screen).

The array contains objects that contains an NSString name property which I want to display in each cell, and also contains an NSString address property which I would like to display in small print below the name property, in the same cell.  The object also has an NSString distance property which I would like to display on the far right of each cell.

My question is:

1. How do I pass the NSArray to the SecondViewController, and display the contents of each index of the NSArray as a cell in a table.
2. How do I customize the appearance of the cell such that it displays the name as the main element, the address property as a sub element, and the distance property, as another sub element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you can create a property "secondArray" in your SecondViewController class synthesize it and release it there and in your FirstViewController class you can initialize that "secondArray" object with contents you want like

```
  //Do something like this in your FirstViewController.m 

  SecondViewController *secondVC =  [[SecondViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil]
  secondVC.secondArray = firstArray; //firstArray would be your local array in FirstViewController
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondVC animated:YES];
```

And then to display the contents in the tableview you will have to create a custom cell with three labels with specific frames that you want in reuseTableViewCellWithIdentifier method.
Then in tableviewCellForRowAtIndexPath method you can initailize the text of the labels by fetching the objects of your "secondArray".

//You can code something like this

```
   -(UITableViewCell *)reuseTableViewCellWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier withIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    UITableViewCell *cell =[[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier]autorelease];
    [cell setFrame:(CGRectMake(0,0,305,50))];


    if([identifier isEqualToString:@"CellIdentifier"])
     {
        //Creating an image view to load the cell image on a table row
        UIImageView *imageView1=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8,8,305,50)];
        imageView1.tag = IMAGEVIEW1_TAG;
        [imageView1 setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[[NSBundle mainBundle]resourcePath]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"AdjustCell.png"]]];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:imageView1];

        //Creating a label to wite "name" on the imageView1 of the table cell
        UILabel *cellText=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(6,5,310,20)];
        cellText.tag = CELLTEXT_TAG;
        cellText.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        cellText.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
        cellText.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15.0];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:cellText];
        [imageView1 addSubview:cellText];  

        //Creating a label to wite distance on the imageView1 of the table cell
        UILabel *distanceText=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(220,27,100,15)];
        distanceText.tag = DISTANCETEXT_TAG;
        distanceText.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        distanceText.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
        distanceText.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0];
        [imageView1 addSubview:distanceText];

        //Creating a label to wite "value" on the imageView2 of the table cell
        UILabel *valueText=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(4,0,150,15)];
        valueText.tag = VALUETEXT_TAG;
        valueText.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        valueText.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
        valueText.font=[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12.0];

        UIImageView *imageView2=[[UIImageView alloc]init];
        imageView2.tag = IMAGEVIEW2_TAG;

        [imageView2 addSubview:partnerText];
        [imageView2 addSubview:valueText];
        [imageView1 addSubview:imageView2];

        [imageView2 release];
        [imageView1 release];
        [valueText release];
        [distanceText release];
        [cellText release];
        [partnerText release];

       }

        - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
    {
        UITableViewCell *cell;  
        static NSString *identifier = @"CellIdentifer";

              cell = [tblView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];


        if(cell == nil)

                cell = [self reuseTableViewCellWithIdentifier:identifier withIndexPath:indexPath];


         NSMutableDictionary *Store = [self.secondArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; //fetch your data here


            UILabel *cellText = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:CELLTEXT_TAG];
            cellText.text = [Store valueForKey:@"name"]; // initialize you data here

            UILabel *distanceText = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:DISTANCETEXT_TAG];
            UILabel *valueText = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:VALUETEXT_TAG];
            valueText.text=[[Store valueForKey:@"value"]uppercaseString];

return cell;
            }
```

Comment: Thanks Shruti for your detailed post.  I really appreciate it.  I do have a follow up question for you.  When you use secondArray in the secondViewController, does it contain the data that you assigned from the firstViewController: secondVC.secondArray = firstArray; ?  Also, because the values for name, address, and distance are all properties of the object that is contained in each index of the array, how do I reference it in your code where you have CELLTEXT_TAG, DISTANCETEXT_TAG, and VALUETEXT_TAG?  I apologize for all of my questions, and I sincerely thank you for your help.

Comment: @syedfa: Ya surely secondArray do contains the contents of firstArray and when you push the view of secondViewController from firstViewController the array is passed automatically with its object. For your second question, you need to define the tags in .m file below import line like this #define IMAGEVIEW1_TAG 11
#define CELLTEXT_TAG 12
#define DISTANCETEXT_TAG 13
#define VALUETEXT_TAG 14
#define IMAGEVIEW2_TAG 15
#define PARTNER_TAG 16

Comment: What do the numbers 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16 refer to?  Are these line numbers in the class?  Can you elaborate a little further as to how we get the references from the object properties from the index linked to the cell contents?  Thanks again for your help.  Take care.

Comment: @syedfa: These are just the tags for your imageviews, labels etc. we are using them to access the imgeview and labels that we set in reuseTableViewCellWithIdentifier.

Comment: I think you've given me enough to help me complete this.  Thanks very much for your time, patience, and help.  Take care.

Answer (score 0):

You should make property for Your array in firstView or declare this array and make this a property in appDelegate.then simply make object of the class (for which this property belongs).then by simply using .operator you can access that arry.

Comment: Thanks very much for your link to the tutorial, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

1. for first question my answer is property. You can create the property of array.
2. for second one, You should use the custom Table View cell. It is the best option. you can create your own design of the cell.

Comment: I think first give him idea how to do that. Don't directly paste the code.

Comment: you have done right. give him link but some people directly paste the code. you can see in this thread. someone has done that.